PyCUDA installation error: "Failed to build wheels for pycuda" while setting up Utrnert repo
I'm trying to clone and set up the Utrnert GitHub repository, but I keep running into an issue with the installation of pycuda. All other dependencies, like pytools and validators, are installed without issues. However, pycuda consistently fails.
Python 3.7  
nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66  
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11==11.7.99  
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11==11.7.99  
nvidia-cudnn-cu11==9.5.0.50  
opencv-contrib-python==4.5.1.48  
opencv-python==4.5.1.48  
packaging==23.0  
Pillow==9.4.0  
pkgutil_resolve_name==1.3.10  
platformdirs==3.1.1  
PyArabic==0.6.15  
pycuda==2022.1  

I suspect it might be a version conflict or a missing dependency, but I’m not sure how to proceed.
Note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.  
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycuda  

Failed to build pycuda  
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycuda, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects.  


Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

You didn't tell us your OS
